# UIImagePickerControllerDelegate has no member 'delegate'

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to do a picker controller for the camera/photo library. The correct option come up but I can't get the details back from the picker.

I have it declared as

```
class Add: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    var imagePickerController : UIImagePickerController!
```

and in my view did load

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
}
```

I'm getting an when trying to set the delegate

> Value of type '(UIImagePickerController,
>   [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) -> ()' has no member
>   'delegate'

If I comment out the delegate line, the code compiles but function afterwards doesn't run

```
@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    // Code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `UINavigationControllerDelegate` conformance to your `Add` ViewController:

```
class Add: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
```